# Get country for a given java TimeZone

Tags: java, android, timezone

I have a java TimeZone object, for example `America/Denver`.  In theory, the [IANA database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IANA_time_zones) lists one country code for that TimeZone, namely `US`.

In java or Android, how can I get the country for a specified TimeZone object?

*UPDATE: Note that I'm not talking about mapping `GMT+0700` to a specific country.  Obviously, there might be multiple countries that map to a single raw offset.  I'm talking about mapping a specific timezone code from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone.tab to its associated singular country code.*

Comment: Refer to this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389837/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-timezone-with-only-a-country-code-valid-iso-3166-code

Comment: @NoobUnChained - He's asking for TZID to country.  Not country to TZID.  This should be possible for anything except administrative zones.  The other direction is what you are talking about, which of course wouldn't work.

Answer (score 7):

In order to map between countries and timezones I used the ICU [library](http://site.icu-project.org/).
Using the com.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(countryCode) method I managed to map timezones to country codes.

```
public static Map<String, String> mapTimezonesToCountries() {
    Map<String, String> timezoneToCountry = new HashMap<>();

    String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();

    for (String countryCode : locales) {
        for (String id : com.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(countryCode))
        {
            // Add timezone to result map

            timezoneToCountry.put(id, countryCode);
        }

    }
    return timezoneToCountry;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, there is no 1:1 relation from TimeZone to Country.
E.g there is also the timeZone "UTC"

Comment: Don't see the problem to return null for UTC or similar. For absolute majority of timezones country code would be neat to have.

Answer (score 0):

The link you gave to zone.tab is actually the source of the data you're looking for.  Of course, you'd want to use one that is [authoritative](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), rather than the copy on Wikipedia.

The IANA/Olson database is implemented in Java with the [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library.  But I don't believe they expose zone.tab via any classes.  At least I couldn't find it.  Please update me if I am incorrect in this.

You can always import the file yourself and use it as needed.

**UPDATE**

I know nothing about Android, but I found something that might make sense to you.  There appears to be a function that exposes the zone.tab data in [libcore.icu.TimeZoneNames.forLocale(locale)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/java/libcore/icu/TimeZoneNames.java)

I searched, but I couldn't find any reference documentation on this.

Comment: yeah, that's my problem.  You would think it would be trivial to expose, but I don't see anywhere where it's exposed in the java/android apis (i hadn't looked at jodatime)

Comment: @emmby - See line # 149 of the link in my update.  Does that help?