# How to Get the Name of TimeZone in Android

Tags: android, timezone

I would like to show the "name" of timezone in my android program. Say if it is "GMT+8:00", then show "HongKong"; By searching, i find that the getDisplayName function should sever my purpose.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDisplayName(boolean, int, java.util.Locale)

However, in my own program, this function only shows "GMT+8:00" but when i use "getDisplayName" in the Google Open Source Project, it would show the name "HongKong" instead.

Does anyone know the reason behind this?

Comment: I would guess it's because timezones go by many names, including just the offset. UTC+8 is actually the most populated timezone in the world, so it has a particularly large number of names, WST, IRKT, Australia/Perth and Asia/Singapore. You'll have to find a subclass of `TimeZone` (and probably of `SimpleTimeZone`) for it to show the name you want.

Answer (score 13):

It's up to you!
You can use `Locale.getDefault()` or a `Calendar` instance.

> `Locale.getDefault()` is not a TimeZone, but specify the language in device

- `Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();`
- `Locale.getDefault()`

.

Below I present some examples:

Printing `Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(TimeZone.getDefault()));` shows:

```
D/MyActivity: libcore.util.ZoneInfo[id="Brazil/East",mRawOffset=-10800000,mEarliestRawOffset=-10800000,mUseDst=true,mDstSavings=3600000,transitions=128]
```

.

Printing `Log.d(LOG_TAG, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());` shows:

`D/MyActivity: Brazil/East`

.

Printing `Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(Locale.getDefault()));` shows:

`D/MyActivity: fr_FR`

.

Printing `Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeZone()));` shows:

```
D/MyActivity: libcore.util.ZoneInfo[id="Brazil/East",mRawOffset=-10800000,mEarliestRawOffset=-10800000,mUseDst=true,mDstSavings=3600000,transitions=128]
```

.

Printing `Log.d(LOG_TAG, calendar.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());` shows:

`D/MyActivity: heure normale de Brasilia`

.

Printing timezone displayName without locale and Timezone SHORT:

`Log.d(LOG_TAG, calendar.getTimeZone().getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT));`

shows output:

`D/MyActivity: GMT-03:00`

.

Printing timezone displayName without locale and Timezone LONG

`Log.d(LOG_TAG, calendar.getTimeZone().getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.LONG));`

shows output:

`D/MyActivity: heure normale de Brasilia`

.

Check the Javadoc for the method you're using:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance(java.util.Locale)

> Gets a calendar using the default time zone and specified locale.

Check this comments to be more clear to you:

- [Is there a way to get a timeZone with a country code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1389996/3332734)
- [How to get abbreviation / Country code of mobile timezone in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29371634/3332734)

Answer (score 7):

You can find out your current time zone by below code

```
private String getTimeZone() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
        TimeZone zone = calendar.getTimeZone();
        return zone.getID();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
System.out.println(tz.getID());
```

`getDisplayName` returns timezone and `getId` returns timezone location name.

Comment: I tried. But this shows "Asia/Hong_Kong" instead of the exact location name. But thanks for your suggestion, it is a bit closer to my preferred way of presentation.

Comment: Asia/Hong_Kong _is_ the ID. What were you expecting? Are you sure it's the timezone name you're after, and not just the location? Hong Kong may be a big city, but it's just one city in a very populated timezone.